# Run a query from Big Query with Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have on Query in my Big Query that I want to execute based on event (when a file arrives in cloud storage bucket)

I tried with a cloud function but it seems to be not working well.

I tried to execute it with this cloud function :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def conn_to_bigquery(request) :

client = bigquery.Client()

# Perform a query.
QUERY = """
    MERGE INTO `vernal-isotope-370113.Pharmacie.docligne` as t  
USING `vernal-isotope-370113.Pharmacie.docligne_inserto` as s   
ON t.DO_Date  = s.DO_Date 
and t.Do_Type = s.DO_Type
and t.CT_Qualite = s.CT_Qualite
and t.Do_souche = s.DO_Souche
and t.Do_piece = s.DO_Piece
and t.AR_Design = s.AR_Design
and t.FA_CodeFamille = s.FA_CodeFamille
and t.FA_Intitule = s.FA_Intitule
and t.AR_Stat01 = s.AR_Stat01
and t.DL_Design = s.DL_Design
and t.FA_Central = s.FA_Central
and t.AR_Ref = s.AR_Ref
and t.AR_RefCompose = s.AR_RefCompose
and t.cbAR_Ref = s.cbAR_Ref
and t.cbAR_RefCompose = s.cbAR_RefCompose
and t.Pharmacie = s.Pharmacie
when matched then 
update set t.DL_MontantHT = s.DL_MontantHT, t.DL_MontantTTC = s.DL_MontantTTC
when not matched then 
INSERT (DO_Date,DO_Type,CT_Qualite,DO_Souche,  DO_Piece,AR_Design,FA_CodeFamille,FA_Intitule, AR_Stat01, DL_Design, FA_Central, AR_Ref, AR_RefCompose, cbAR_Ref, cbAR_RefCompose, DL_MontantHT, DL_MontantTTC, Pharmacie ) 
VALUES (s.DO_Date,s.DO_Type,s.CT_Qualite, s.DO_Souche, s.DO_Piece,s.AR_Design,s.FA_CodeFamille,s.FA_Intitule, s.AR_Stat01, s.DL_Design, s.FA_Central, s.AR_Ref, s.AR_RefCompose, s.cbAR_Ref, s.cbAR_RefCompose, s.DL_MontantHT, s.DL_MontantTTC, s.Pharmacie )
"""
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request

return f"The query run successfully"
```

But I get an error message in logs :

> Cloud FunctionsUpdateFunctionus-central1:docligne_merge_sqlkevin.rabemananjara93@gmail.com {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction, resourceName: projects/vernal-isotope-370113/locations/us-central1/functions/docligne_merge_sql, serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com, s…

Do you guys know what causes this error and how to fix it ?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def conn_to_bigquery(request) :

client = bigquery.Client()

# Perform a query.
QUERY = """
    MERGE INTO `vernal-isotope-370113.Pharmacie.docligne` as t  
USING `vernal-isotope-370113.Pharmacie.docligne_inserto` as s   
ON t.DO_Date  = s.DO_Date 
and t.Do_Type = s.DO_Type
and t.CT_Qualite = s.CT_Qualite
and t.Do_souche = s.DO_Souche
and t.Do_piece = s.DO_Piece
and t.AR_Design = s.AR_Design
and t.FA_CodeFamille = s.FA_CodeFamille
and t.FA_Intitule = s.FA_Intitule
and t.AR_Stat01 = s.AR_Stat01
and t.DL_Design = s.DL_Design
and t.FA_Central = s.FA_Central
and t.AR_Ref = s.AR_Ref
and t.AR_RefCompose = s.AR_RefCompose
and t.cbAR_Ref = s.cbAR_Ref
and t.cbAR_RefCompose = s.cbAR_RefCompose
and t.Pharmacie = s.Pharmacie
when matched then 
update set t.DL_MontantHT = s.DL_MontantHT, t.DL_MontantTTC = s.DL_MontantTTC
when not matched then 
INSERT (DO_Date,DO_Type,CT_Qualite,DO_Souche,  DO_Piece,AR_Design,FA_CodeFamille,FA_Intitule, AR_Stat01, DL_Design, FA_Central, AR_Ref, AR_RefCompose, cbAR_Ref, cbAR_RefCompose, DL_MontantHT, DL_MontantTTC, Pharmacie ) 
VALUES (s.DO_Date,s.DO_Type,s.CT_Qualite, s.DO_Souche, s.DO_Piece,s.AR_Design,s.FA_CodeFamille,s.FA_Intitule, s.AR_Stat01, s.DL_Design, s.FA_Central, s.AR_Ref, s.AR_RefCompose, s.cbAR_Ref, s.cbAR_RefCompose, s.DL_MontantHT, s.DL_MontantTTC, s.Pharmacie )
"""
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request

return f"The query run successfully"
```

Comment: I created a service account for accessing BigQuery and included it in the credential of the cloud function. There is a config menu to do this step. Please include how do you included your credentials.

Comment: I personally cannot deduct anything from the error. Nevertheless, Is your cloud function getting triggered by the cloud event(in your case change in storage buket)? Does the Service Account associated with the Cloud Function has the necessary permissions to BigQuery?